# i have two accounts on my iphone

Tags: iphone

I can't update anything on my iphone because suddenly I have two accounts and I don't know the password of one of them.
I tried to delete that account but I can't find that account anywhere on my iphone.
please help me!
How can I delete this account?

Comment: What kind of account? In the appstore?

Comment: yes in the App Store

Comment: Also - downwiting this since minimal troubleshooting isn't done. You don't specify what version of iOS. You didn't link to an Apple Support article and it's really not clear what you do and don't understand. Have a look at the help center - especially the article on [how to ask a good question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume you're talking about updating apps.
Your Apple ID that is used as standard for the App Store is in the AppStore pane of yours devices settings app.
However, if you have downloaded apps with a different Apple ID you will be asked for *that* Apple ID when updating a App which has been downloaded with said AppleID.

Or as short: the AppleID/password which needs to be entered when updating an App is the always the one which was used to first download said App.

You can reset the password of an AppleID on [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to make a backup of your iPhone and then wipe it.

Settings app - general - erase all content and settings.

At that point it will reboot and you can enter just one account and make sure it works.

Make notes of exactly which screen you enter exactly which account.

Once you've sorted out the dozen or so places where an Apple ID can be used, you can then decide if you want to wipe again and restore the backup or just start using the phone with the new account settings solidly in place.